# Laravel 8 - Facade Class Not Found

Tags: php, laravel

I have been struggling with this after trying to replicate simple tutorials to get started a new project.

Folllowing the tutorials here: https://medium.com/@cmanish049/creating-custom-facades-in-laravel-b9b72d573752

1. Created The Helper Function

   ```
    namespace App\CSVUtils;

     class CSVParser
     {

       public function sayHello()
       {
        echo "Hello, from Facade class.";
       }
     }
   ```
2. Created The Service Provider

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   use App\CSVUtils\CSVParser;

   class CsvParserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('csvparser',function(){

            return new CSVParser();

         });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind('csvparser',function(){

            return new CSVParser();

         });
      }
    }
   ```
3. Created the Facade

   ```
   <?
   namespace App\CSVUtils;

   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

   class CSVParserFacade extends Facade
   {
     protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
     {
       return 'csvparser';
     }
   }
   ```
4. Added the following to the app/config.php (I did not remove any of the default entries just added the following

   ```
   'providers' => [
        App\Providers\CsvParserServiceProvider::class,
        ...
      ],

    'aliases' => [

        'CSV' => App\CSVUtiles\CSVParserFacade::class,

        ...
    ]
   ```
5. Called the Alias in the my controller

   ```
   <?php

     use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

     Route::get('/csv', function () {

       CSV::sayHello();

      //return view('welcome');
     });
   ```

RESULT:

> ErrorException Class "App\CSVUtiles\CSVParserFacade" not found
> http://localhost/csv
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php:80

I have tried a bunch of things, renaming classes / files changing the namespace, calling the Facade directly (rather than from the alias)

I have also tried the following:

composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled

And now I feel like I'm loosing my mind. It's been a busy day and my brain is fried but I'm hoping I am missing something simple.

Please help!! :)

Comment: do you try ```php artisan optimize:clear```?

Comment: everything seems good. but why are you bind your class twice in provider?

Comment: your spelling is incorrect, App\CSVUtils\CSVParserFacade instead of App\CSVUtiles\CSVParserFacade, just remove 'e'

Comment: Still struggling with this. I have removed the 'e' and even run php artisan optimize:clear however I am still seeing the same Class "App\CSVUtils\Facades\CSVParserFacade" not found

Answer (score 1):

This is a machine translation, so the text may be wrong.
I had the same phenomenon and I will share the cause in my case.

To compare to the example, it was due to the fact that the directory should have been created with "CSVUtils", but it was whitespaced with "CSVUtils ".

Answer (score 0):

Update below code - aliases for CSV :

```json
'providers' => [
     App\Providers\CsvParserServiceProvider::class,
     ...
   ],

 'aliases' => [

     'CSV' => App\CSVUtils\CSVParserFacade::class,

     ...
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I see someone else pointed out the same issue.  After going back through my code and correcting the typo this did not resolve my issue - I am still having the same issue:  ErrorException
Class "App\Facades\CSVFacade" not found

Answer (score 0):

Just a little spelling mistake. Correct the spelling in app.php aliases array.

Use this line of code

'CSV' => App\CSVUtils\CSVParserFacade::class,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. I appreciate the response.  I did resolve this issue however I am still seeing exactly the same issue. I tried renaming all directories I still see the same issue